# store images and display in different classes

Tags: java, image, class, get, awt

I'm trying to get mutiple images in 'GetImage' class, and disply them in the main class.

Can anybody show me an example how to do it?? I tried bunch of other samples but they didn't work since I have two classes.

Here is one that I tried.

main clss:

```
import java.awt.*;
import hsa.*;

public class Test
{
static Console c;  

    public void Display()
    {
        GetImage c = new GetImage();
        c.paint(g);
    }

    public Test()
    {
        c = new Console ();
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Test = new Test();
        a.Display();

    }

}
```

seperate class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import hsa.Console;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GetImage extends Frame
{

    Image image;
    String imageName = "ImageFileName.jpg";

    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        Toolkit tool = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ();
        image = tool.getImage (imageName);
        g.drawImage (image, 30, 30, this); // location of the image
        g.drawString (imageName, 100, 50); // location of the name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with the hsa package, but some quick googling says it's an educational package from some company that has since gone out of business, correct me if I'm wrong. So personally I'd try to avoid using any of their stuff if you can.

If you have to use this for school or something then you probably want to stick entirely with their package instead of mix and matching hsa with awt. Something like this might accomplish what you want, but again I'm not familiar with the hsa package.

```
import java.awt.*;
import hsa.*;

public class Test
{
    static Console c;  

    public void Display()
    {
        GetImage gI = new GetImage(c,25,80,12);
    }

    public Test()
    {
        c = new Console ();
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Test = new Test();
        a.Display();

    }

}


import java.awt.*;
import hsa.ConsoleCanvasGraphics;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GetImage extends ConsoleCanvasGraphics
{

    Image image, image2;
    String imageName = "ImageFileName.jpg", image2Name = "Image2FileName.jpg";
    public GetImage(ConsoleParent parent, int rows, int columns, int fontSize)
    {
        Toolkit tool = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ();
        image = tool.getImage (imageName);
        image2 = tool.getImage (image2Name);
        super(parent,rows,columns,fontSize);
        drawImage(image,30,30,this);
        drawImage(image2,30,60,this);
        drawString(imageName,100,50,new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN,  20),Color.BLACK);
        drawString(image2Name,100,80,new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN,  20),Color.BLACK);
    }

}
```

Again, I'd try to avoid hsa myself, but if you're set on using it and need to have two separate classes in your program then the above should be a rough outline of something that might work.